# Calculating Multiple Averages

Tags: excel, vba

It's my first time posting a question to this forum.  Though I have found answers here many times before, I have been unable to find a solution to my current predicament.

I work in a call center and each week I need to analyze data from the thousands of call that took place over the week.  I'm new to programming in Excel-VBA but I've been able to get pretty far.

The data is produced by a third party program and the format is nigh unreadable.  Much of the programming I've done so far has been geared towards making the data more organized.  Now, I'd like to get into more analysis.

The data is arranged by employee number (NOT in order, though).  Each employee takes several calls over the course of the week, some for which the customer takes a survey.  It's the survey scores I want.  I want to take the average of all the surveys for each employee and then display that average in the same row as each of the entries.

Example
[image]

The yellow highlighted area is what I want to add.  Any ideas?  Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA. If you have the supported version of Excel you can use [AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642). If not you can use below formula.

Enter as an array formula by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when exiting cell edit mode (instead of just enter).

```
=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$B$2:$B$13))
```

Then copy down for all rows.

Comment: That will definitely help!  However, the page I'm dealing with is thousands of rows deep.  A macro would enable me to get this done much faster. Here's what I've got so far: `Range(P2).Value = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Range("B:B"), "12345", Range("L:L"))`    However, this is throwing up an error, "Unable to get the AverageIf property of the WorksheetFunction class.

Comment: @Frnht451 - look at the link I provided for AverageIF. It requires certain versions of Excel.

Comment: @Frnht451 if your Excel version does not support `AverageIf` (version prior to Excel 2007), you can always use `Application.Evaluate(someFormula)`. The formula would be what the answer proposes, with the modified ranges to fit your data.